# weird behaviour when executing python script

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I don't know if any of you have ever had such a behaviour, but after debugging my code I noticed a really weird thing happening to my code.
Basically, I am filling a numpy array ('vols') with values contained in a pandas dataframe (with 2 hierarchical columns) at a certain index ('date'), but if I try to execute this piece of code in a script:

```
   for i in range(capEndDates_size):
      for j in range(strike_size):         
       vols[i,j] = float(df[capEndDates[i]][strikes_list[j]].ix[date])
```

I cannot properly fill all values of variable 'vols' with those included in the dataframe at index 'date', instead getting some 'nan' where I would expect values.
The funny thing is that if I execute the piece of code in the interpreter, this goes the right way (i.e. by pressing f9 on the editor of Spyder, which is the IDE I'm using)! I found a workaround at this bug by repeating those lines twice (that is, forcing the script to execute the lines two times). 
My solution is like this:

```
   for i in range(capEndDates_size):
      for j in range(strike_size):         
       vols[i,j] = float(df[capEndDates[i]][strikes_list[j]].ix[date])

   for i in range(capEndDates_size):
      for j in range(strike_size):         
       vols[i,j] = float(df[capEndDates[i]][strikes_list[j]].ix[date])
```

Which is really unacceptable.
Does any one have an idea of why this is happening?

Comment: nan typically stands for not a number which is what would happen if it is expecting a number but gets an array or some other nun numeric type.

Comment: thanks ajon, but the fact is that the dataframe does not contain nans, and in fact, if I execute the code twice, the variable GETS filled with the right values, whereas if the code is executed only once it gets nans...

Comment: Can you put up a complete example that shows the behavior, so that we can try?

Comment: ouch.... this is a bit hard, since it's part of a more complex project, involving more modules I created and a dataframe which is pickled down from previous scripts and loaded in this one.... I might try to replicate the behaviour as part of a simpler code, hope I can manage!

Comment: Could you show how you create the data frame?
By the way, instead of rewriting the code you could use a `for _ in range(2):`.

Comment: the DataFrame gets created by reading txt files using the csv reader module.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try inserting a hard break point (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) after the assignment to `vols` if `vols[i,j]` is NaN and debug that way?

Comment: hello Wes, that's how I found out that the vols variable wouldnt get filled with values, but coulnd't understand why this was happening even in debugging